# Sentences starting with the preposition "Of"

Tags: prepositions

I often see sentences starting with the prepositions "In", "With", "To", and "For".
However, a sentence starting with "Of" seems to be quite rare.
Is that grammatically correct? For example, what about the following complicated sentence?

*Of our shelves A, B, C, and D, for B and C, you can take any book from there; for A and D, you cannot.*

Comment: Of the many reasons for . . . .Try a Google Ngram search with Of * (it's case sensitive if you don't check the box).  Of course you can figure out an odd sentence, as you have, that sounds awkward.

Comment: Your use of 'of' sounds odd in your example because one wouldn't say, "You can take any book **of** our shelves."

Comment: Of course, you can use "of" at the beginning of a sentence! :)

Comment: Your sentence is not natural. Where did you find it?

Comment: I appreciate you all responded my question. The awkward sentence is what I devised for asking my question. Thanks again your helpful comments!

Answer (score 1):

*Of the comments on the question, one is yours and the rest are by other people.*

Note that valid sentences of this form can be rearranged:

> Of the comments on the question, one is yours and the rest are by other people.
>
> One *of the comments on the question* is yours and the rest *of the comments on the question* are by other people.

Because "of the comments on the question" occurs twice, you can bring it to the front. This is rather like factorisation in algebra: *ax+bx → x*(*a+b*).

However, to start a sentence with *of,* that preposition must make sense. In your example sentence, you have also included the prepositions *for* and *from*. You have too many prepositions. Any sentence is awkward.

> ✗ Of our shelves A, B, C, and D, for B and C, you can take any book from there; for A and D, you cannot.
>
> ✗ Of our shelves A, B, C and D, you can take any book from B and C; you cannot from A and D.
>
> ✓ From our shelves B and C, you can take any book; from shelves A and D, you cannot.